# How to unescape the value of a cookie using CGI in Perl on the Server Side?

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

I am trying to send a list of words separated by commas inside the value of a cookie back to the browser, using CGI in Perl, but the comma symbol is always converted to "%2C":

```
top%2Cchay%2Cpisi
```

The code is the following:

```
$ud        = 'top,chay,pisi';
$cookie_ud = CGI::Cookie->new(
-name    => 'ud',
-value   => $ud,
-expires => '+25y'
);
print "Set-Cookie: $cookie_ud\n";
```

I am doing this because I have to pass this data to a program which I haven't developed.
How can avoid the commas from being escaped in the server side application? I want the value of the cookie equal to "top,chay,pisi" instead of "top%2Cchay%2Cpisi".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, commas are escaped, as are any other special characters. What is your question?

Comment: I don't want the commas to be escaped, when the list gets to the browser.

Comment: I am new to CGI in Perl, how? I cannot alter the client application.

Comment: Ah, now THERE is a question....

Comment: If you need to un-escape it in the browser, you'll have to do it in javascript.

Comment: @Flimzy I can't do it in JavaScript, I am just providing the server side application like a web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGI::Cookie automatically escapes any special characters in the cookie names and values when it renders the cookie as a string.  It does not provide any method for disabling or bypassing this because<strike>, although escaping is not required by the cookie specification,</strike> the cookie specification states that servers SHOULD NOT send cookies containing unescaped commas (among other characters).  Plus, it's just plain good security practice.

If you really, *really* need to send cookies containing unescaped raw data (and this is *not* recommended), you'll need to unescape the cookie string before printing it.

```
use CGI::Util 'unescape';
print "Set-Cookie: " . unescape "$cookie_ud" . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you in fact certain the client side doesn't handle the escaped commas properly?  If it doesn't, it is a bug in the client.  Cookie values are supposed to be url-escaped, and unescaped commas in particular are forbidden in valid cookies:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1:

```
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                   ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                   ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                   ; and backslash
```